# python 2 simple for loop high memory usage

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, memory-management, iterator

Testing with Python 2.7 and 3.5

```
for i in range(0, 1000000000):
    pass
```

When I'm running this code with python3 everything is fine (less than 3MB memory usage)

But by python2 memory usage is 32GB (my server has only 32GB of ram)

How to fix this for Python 2.7?

Comment: In Python 3, `range()` creates an iterator, but in Python 2 `range()` creates a list.  In Python 2, use `xrange()` instead to create an iterator.

Comment: Try using `xrange()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range` in Python 2.7 and `range` in Python 3 are different functions. In Python 3 it returns an iterator which provides values one by one. In Python 2.7 it returns an array for which some memory has to be allocated. It can be solved by using `xrange` function in Python version 2.7.

```
Python 2.7.12
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> xrange(10)
xrange(10)
>>> iterator = iter(xrange(10))
>>> iterator.next()
0
>>> iterator.next()
1
>>> iterator.next()
2
```